# Call another model field in url django

Tags: python, django

My problem is have two models job and company and i want to get all jobs in this company

My urls.py:

```
url(r'^jobs/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.job_at_company, name='job_at_company'),
```

My views.py:

```
def job_at_company(request, slug):
    return render(request, 'jobs.html')
```

My models.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
     slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, default='')
     city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
     contact_info = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=0)
     facebook = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
     twitter = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
     linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
     logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logo", default=0)

class Jobs(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, default='')
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     price = models.IntegerField(default='')
     Description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     job_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=(('Full Time', 'Full Time'),('Part Time', 'Part Time')),default='Full Time')
```

Answer (score 0):

in the views.py we can add this

```
def job_at_company(request, slug):
    results = Jobs.objects.filter(company__slug=slug)

    context = {'items':results}

    return render(request, 'jobs.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you pass `id` in the `url`. The `id` is the `primary key` of the company. You would have to modify your `url` to accept `id` like -

```
url(r'^jobs/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', views.job_at_company, name='job_at_company')
```

And modify your views.py -

```
def job_at_company(request, slug, pk):
    jobs_qs = Jobs.objects.filter(company__id=pk)
    return render(request, 'jobs.html', {'jobs': jobs_qs})
```

And use it in your html like -

```
{% for job in jobs %}
    {{job.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

Look at this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). Django's documentation is helpful, follow that